# Sqlite console to check the results of Queries.

Tags: android, sqlite, user-interface, console

well I just want to see results of my queries performed by my 'Android' application using 'Sqlite'. Is there any console or GUI available for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Try sqlite manager in firefox browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's also [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) which is nice, and works good. (at least on the desktop).